# JQuery - Dynamic Img Src Attr Change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Could somebody Explain, What is the Problem with this Code. Once the html is opened in Web Browser, the image is not getting dynamically changed at interval periods.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Blinking Text</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var x;
        setInterval(function() {
                if(x == 0) {
                        $('blinking').attr('src', "http://www.example.com/images/banner1.png");         
                        x = 1;
                } else  {
                    if(x = 1) {
                        $('blinking').attr('src', "http://www.example.com/images/banner2.png");             
                        x = 0;
                    }
                }
        }, 750);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="blinking"><img src="http://www.example.com/images/banner1.png"></img></div>
</table>    
</body>
</html>
```

- thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget to add `class selector` for image.

```
$('.blinking img')
```

`$('.blinking img')` means you are selecting `image` whose `parent` is `blinking div`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with jQuery selector `$('blinking')`

If you are selecting by class it should be `$('.blinking img')`. Notice `.`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.blinking img');
```

`$('div.blinking')` --> `div` with class `blinking`.

`$('div.blinking img');` --> image whose parent is div with class blinking.

Answer (score 1):

This $("blinking") doesn't mean anything to jQuery it thinks you are looking ro and element blinking if you are selecting class you need to specify its prefix selector example:

```
//CLASS
$(".blinking")
//ID
$("#blinking")
```

I suggest you to read [this](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)